# Android device not recognized by ADB, USB Debug blinking (Mi 11 Lite 5G)

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, xiaomi, usb-debugging

I get troubles connecting my android devices through USB debugging to my MacBook Pro.
ADB partially detect the android devices which is blinking a `USB Debugging Popup`.

For information : I tried to change USB cables, adaptators, and reset to factory parameters the device, same problem. I tried with another Android phone (Huawei P20 PRO) and everything works perfectly.

So. I got a `Mi 11 Lite 5G` for developping purposes, here is the specifications :

- `Android Version : 11 RKQ1.201112.002`
- `MIUI Version : MIUI Global 12.5.6(RKIEUXM) Stable`
- `Developper options : Activated`
- `USB Debug : Activated`
- `MIUI Optimisation : Desactivated`
- `Reset to factory parameters`

When connecting through USB Cables to my MacBook Pro and after typing `adb devices` it start to blink "USB Debugging Popup" (here is a video : https://youtu.be/Jcn3Atfi7tU ). It doesn't blink if I didn't run `adb devices` command. It stopped blinking if I play `adb kill-server` (however, it restart again once I clicked on the device).

On my MacBook Pro, the command : `adb devices` gave no devices connected.
Here is the version of ADB :

```
~ adb version 
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
Version 31.0.3-7562133
Installed as /usr/local/bin/adb
```

However, on `Android Studio 2020.3.1 Patch 4`, here is what I got on the connection Assistant, the devices seems to be recognized for a milisecond each time (here is a video : https://www.loom.com/share/f70b27885d884cbdadcc5a7c4b56f7f6 ).

Assuming the USB Cable is OK, Adaptator is OK, Android Studio and ADB are updated, another Android Phone is detected, what is the problem with this `Mi 11 Lite 5G` which was working like two month ago and doesn't have been touched since ?

Comment: I am having the same problem with Mi 11 Lite 5G. Every time I turn on USB debugging, the popup starts blinking. If i turn USB debugging off, the blinking stops. So the problem isn't really related to the cable. Please let me know if you could solve this issue.

Comment: The problem is relative to ADB / Xiaomi version, if you enter the command `adb kill-server` it's gonna stop blinking. If you enter `adb devices` it's gonna infinity blink.

Comment: Having the exact same problem. Using the latest `Version 32.0.0-8006631` of adb and running the same MIUI version. I'm working around using adb over WiFi, which works quite well. Once in a while I have to run `adb kill-server` for the device to get discovered again.

Answer (score 0):

The blinking looks like an improper connection still try to enable the debug options from settings and check if particularly USB debug option is checked on. Also go through the entire options maybe there is some new option related to side loading that MI might have provided.

Also check if there is some anti virus software on your Mac I have McAfee and it interferes a lot while Android debugging so I have to sometimes turn it off.

Comment: It doesn't work. I didn't have any antivirus, and I desactivated all weird option other than USB debugging. However, I noticed that the blinking appears ONLY if I run `adb devices` or try to identify the device on my MacBook Pro. After restarting the device, it doesn't blink at all, so I ran `adb devices`. The output was empty and it started blinking from there.

Comment: @GuillaumeRZ I googled a bit and MI devices require some PC suite to run properly if it is not available for mac you can use https://www.sync-mac.com/ but this needs to be installed on both mac and phone

Comment: Thank you, can you give me your sources ? Because the `Mi 11 Lite 5G` was working well with my mac two months ago. I didn't touch it since.

Answer (score 0):

Updating to the latest ADB finally fixed the issue for me.

Also make sure to enable the `USB debugging (Security Settings)` setting in addition to `USB debugging`, and `Install via USB` for Android Studio to work properly with the phone.

I'm running

```
❯ adb --version
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
Version 33.0.0-8141338
```